# TextView, how to display prompt for user

Tags: android, textview

I need to set prompt for my TextView, if String is too long to fit inside TV (i set max length 20) then it displays only part of it with "..." at the end. I want to display prompt with full String when i click on TV. Is it possible? And if yes then how to do it?

[image: like this, but without close button, just disappearing after short amount of time]

Inside activity:

```
textCompany.setText(testDb.getCompanyName(id));
textCompany.setEllipsize(null);
```

And XML:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCompany"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textId"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"

            android:text="verylongstringjusttotestifthisworksandletshopeitwill" />
```

Comment: Where do you want to display the full textview?

Comment: Do you want a Alert Dialog type popup?

Comment: For example above the text view, or any other side, for short amount of time, something like message cloud with suggestion

Comment: yes, sorry for my language, i ment popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a simple onClickListener. First, you check what the length of the text is, then if it's more than 20 characters, you take the first 20 and add three dots to the end and display that. At the same time, you save the full text to a temporary variable, and you display it when someone clicks your TextView.

```
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textCompany);
            String shortMessage;
            final String message = textView.getText().toString();
            if(message.length() >= 20){
                shortMessage = message.substring(0,19)+"...";
                textView.setText(shortMessage);
            }
            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

        }
```

Note: make sure you make your textView clickable by adding the following to your xml:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: Thank's for this solution. Finally i used simple pop up, which disappears, when looses focus (usable if company name is really long, to make time to read it), but your solution fully answers question i've asked.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you mentioned is due to

**android:ellipsize="end"**

It displays the end of text with "Some text..." if it does not fit in width.
You can programmatically change the ellipsize value to none to display the full text on Click.

```
myTextView.setEllipsize(null);
```